# How to override Catalog Price Rules?

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I'm trying to create a module which i'm hoping will extend the Catalog Price Rules feature to allow me to create pricing groups based on Cost plus a percentage (e.g. All products in a category are cost + 30% for specific customer group).

Firstly, how can I ensure that Magento uses this price even if it is higher than the base price??

Secondly, Which files do i need to override?
So far, i've located:

- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Helper/Data.php - this contains the rule logic
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule.php - this contains the validation rules
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Product.php - i think this contains the options for the rule logic
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Action/SimpleActionOptionsProvider.php - this also contains the options for the rule logic
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Observer/ProcessAdminFinalPriceObserver.php & ProcessFrontFinalPriceObserver.php

Are there any others?

The last thing is that i will obviously need to parse the product cost into these functions, what would be the best way to do that?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Did you get this working? We are trying to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All good, i figured it all out.

- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Helper/Data.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Product.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Action/SimpleActionOptionsProvider.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Observer/ProcessAdminFinalPriceObserver.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Observer/ProcessFrontFinalPriceObserver.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php
- vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Indexer/IndexBuilder.php

were the files i needed in case anyone is interested

Comment: do you have any idea how can I add custom price rules instead of catalog price rules? I want to extend it with alot more features forexample: giving discount on the basis of custom attributes on products, giving discount on specific product, giving discount on the basis of my own attributes on products.