# Magento 2: Add cart price rule for unique customer

Tags: magento2, customer, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I'd need to create price rules for an unique customer, like:

For certain products:

General: 0% discount
Retailer: 5% discount
Wholesale: 10% discount
Customer1: 20% discount
Customer2: 22% discount
Customer3: 15% discount
etc.

I know you can do a group customer for an unique customer, but I think I will work better having directly the option to add price rule for a certain customer.

I thought about adding another field below Customer groups: "Customers" And could add ID customer inside the field.

But I have no idea how to begin, you think it will be a nightmare?

Comment: Did you have any success here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to override the functionality of `Catalog-rule` module.
I created a new module and with preferences I finally made it.

For more information follow this link: [How to override Catalog Price Rules?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140565/how-to-override-catalog-price-rules)

With that you can override all this functionality